# Can someone explain what this piece of code is doing...[ Instantiating a specific object from a class ]

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, block

I need some clarification on what or how the object below is being created.

Mechanically, I understand that this is creating an instance to particular button located within the tableview but I'm not  quite sure of the method call itself. Can someone please explain to me what's going on with the script within the block? Is there a special name for this?

```
[OAUtility likePhotoInBackground:self.userPhotoObject block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

OAPhotoHeaderView *actualHeaderView = (OAPhotoHeaderView *) [self tableView:self.tableView viewForHeaderInSection:button.tag] ; 

...

}];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code call method likePhotoInBackground:block on OAUtility class.
You pass `self.userPhotoObject` as a first parameter and block which pass two parameters succeeded and error. Inside that block (I believe it's completion one) you call another method which return `actualHeaderView` object, subclass of `OAPhotoHeaderView`

Comment: Thanks Greg. So this...[self tableView:self.tableView viewForHeaderInSection:button.tag] is actually a method inside the PhotoHeaderView class? =

Comment: No it's method inside self (subclass of table view controller) which will be run after likePhotoInBackground:block method finished. This method (tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:) it's table view delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is not creating an object. It's invoking a class method in the class OAUtility, and passing that method a block of code.

The method is likePhotoInBackground:block:

It looks like the likePhotoInBackground:block: method takes 2 parameters, a "photo object" and a block of code.

Code blocks are kind of like C function pointers. They are executable code that can take parameters and return a result.

In this case, the block does not return a result. It takes a BOOL named succeeded, and a pointer to an NSError object.

It looks like the code in the block fetches a header view from a particular section of a table view, based on a button's tag value.

Aside from that, it's hard to know more about what's going on. We would need to know about the OAUtility class and it's methods, and about the setup of the table view, it's buttons, etc.

Comment: Thanks Duncan! I understand what's going on with OAUtility and even the block, what I don't get is this part...(OAPhotoHeaderView *) [self tableView:self.tableView viewForHeaderInSection:button.tag]  I'm used to seeing object *myobject = [object alloc]init]...